# auth0 custom DB connection Postgres Connection Error

Tags: node.js, auth0

We are using auth0 for user authentication & authorization, and configured custom DB with postgresDB.

Auth0 account is using node 16 as runtime engine for running custom DB scripts.
Loaded postgres template and modified with required changes.
When testing the script, it was giving error saying **postgres.connection is not a function**.

The same code works well for other account which have node 12 as runtime.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue when using old version of pg.

Latest pg version supported in Auth0 is 8.7.1

Ref: https://auth0-extensions.github.io/canirequire/#pg

So you can update the statement

```
require('pg')
```

to

```
require('pg@8.7.1')
```

Also please refere https://node-postgres.com/apis/client for correct way to use the Client from pg.